# Can I set an automatic content processor for custom filetypes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation, xna, xna-4.0

In xna, when I add a file of a type that visual studio doesn't recognize, I have to manually set the Content processor and Content importer. Is there a way to auto detect a custom filetype?

Comment: I don't mind if there isn't as long as there's some proof

Comment: If you start using custom importers, I'd recommend reading Shawn Hargreaves' posts on the content pipeline and Intermediate Serializer. You'll find problems along the way for which Shawn almost always has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this -- it seems to work just fine with my own custom importers.  When you define your custom importer, one of the values specified in the ContentImporterAttribute is the file extension.  Here's an example from my own code:

```
[ContentImporter(".guiobj", DisplayName = "GuiObject Importer", DefaultProcessor = "GuiObjectProcessor")]
```

Now, whenever I add a file to the content project with a .guiobj extension, Visual Studio automatically sets the importer and processor.

Comment: What about using the standard XML file importer, where could I put this? Would I have to create some kind of wrapper? I'd rather not

Comment: I don't think there any way to do it with the built-in importers.  Sorry.